# Plotting a dataframe as both a 'hist' and 'kde' on the same plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, dataframe

I have a pandas `dataframe` with user information. I would like to plot the age of users as both a `kind='kde'` and on `kind='hist'` on the same plot. At the moment I am able to have the two separate plots. The dataframe resembles:

```
member_df=    
user_id    Age
1          23
2          34
3          63 
4          18
5          53  
...
```

using

```
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,3), (0,0))
member_df.Age.plot(kind='kde', xlim=[16, 100])
ax1.set_xlabel('Age')

ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((2,3), (0,1))
member_df.Age.plot(kind='hist', bins=40)
ax2.set_xlabel('Age')

ax3 = ...
```

I understand that the `kind='kde'` will give me frequencies for the y-axis whereas  `kind='kde'` will give a cumulative distribution, but is there a way to combine both and have the y-axis be represented by the frequencies?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`pd.DataFrame.plot()` returns the `ax` it is plotting to.  You can reuse this for other plots.

Try:

```
ax = member_df.Age.plot(kind='kde')
member_df.Age.plot(kind='hist', bins=40, ax=ax)
ax.set_xlabel('Age')
```

***example***
I plot `hist` first to put in background
Also, I put `kde` on `secondary_y` axis

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 2), columns=list('ab'))

ax = df.a.plot(kind='hist')
df.a.plot(kind='kde', ax=ax, secondary_y=True)
```

[image]

---

***response to comment***
using `subplot2grid`.  just reuse `ax1`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,3), (0,0))

np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 2), columns=list('ab'))

df.a.plot(kind='hist', ax=ax1)
df.a.plot(kind='kde', ax=ax1, secondary_y=True)
```

[image]

Comment: I've tested the code and attempted to modify it slightly for what I need. This does the trick for when I only have those two plots to consider.  When I attempt to include into `sublot2grid`  it fails to produce the same outcome, it is only reproduces the histogram.

Comment: @Lukasz you want to use the same `ax` in any case.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want it for all the columns of your dataframe:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(8,3, figsize=(20, 50)) 
# you can change the distribution, I had 22 columns, so 8x3 is fine to me
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace = .2, wspace=.2, )

ax = ax.ravel()

for i in range(len(I_df.columns)):
    ax[i] = I_df.iloc[:,i].plot(kind='hist', ax=ax[i])
    ax[i] = I_df.iloc[:,i].plot(kind='kde', ax=ax[i], secondary_y=True)
    plt.title(I_df.columns[i])
```

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

It is better and even simpler to use [seaborn.displot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html). Prior proposed solutions had KDE plot appear a little "shifted up" for me. `seaborn.distplot` accurately lined up zeros between hist and kde plots. 
`import seaborn as sns
 sns.displot(df.a)`

Comment: ... which is deprecated.