# Superimposition of histogram and density in Pandas/Matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram, seaborn

I've got a Pandas dataframe named `clean` which contains a column `v` for which I would like to draw a histogram and superimpose a density plot. I know I can plot one under the other this way:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Maxv=200

plt.subplot(211)
plt.hist(clean['v'],bins=40, range=(0, Maxv), color='g')
plt.ylabel("Number")

plt.subplot(212)
ax=clean['v'].plot(kind='density')
ax.set_xlim(0, Maxv)
plt.xlabel("Orbital velocity (km/s)")
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```

[image]

But when I try to superimpose, y scales doesn't match (and I loose y axis ticks and labels):

```
yhist, xhist, _hist = plt.hist(clean['v'],bins=40, range=(0, Maxv), color='g')
plt.ylabel("Number")

ax=clean['v'].plot(kind='density') #I would like to insert here a normalization to max(yhist)/max(ax)
ax.set_xlim(0, Maxv)
plt.xlabel("Orbital velocity (km/s)")
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```

[image]

Some hint? (Additional question: how can I change the width of density smoothing?)

Comment: [this answer should help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39987117/2336654)

Comment: Yes it does, thank you. I just have to find away of setting x range size and hiding the second y-axis... Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you use [`seaborn`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html#plotting-univariate-distributions)?

Comment: Is it easier in seaborn ?

Comment: No I try this: 
    
    ax = clean.v.plot(kind='hist', bins=40, range=(0, Maxv))
    clean.v.plot(kind='kde', ax=ax, secondary_y=True)
    
 But the range part doesn't work, and ther's still the left y-axis problem

Comment: @Matt without the data it's hard to say, but yes, seaborn is meant to make difficult things easy ;)

Comment: Additional answer: in seaborn you can change density smoothing with the parameter `bw`. Just sayin'

Comment: @IanS I'm looking at your seaborn lik, it may be a very good option too. Thanks!

Comment: Seaborn has a top-level function that does exactly this: http://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/distplot_options.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No I try this:

```
ax = clean.v.plot(kind='hist', bins=40, range=(0, Maxv))
clean.v.plot(kind='kde', ax=ax, secondary_y=True)
```

But the range part doesn't work, and ther's still the left y-axis problem

[image]

Comment: Try setting the range after plotting: `ax.set(xlim=[0, Maxv])`

Comment: For the left y-axis see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17877159/5276797).

Comment: @IanS: thank you very much, it works for the range. :) I haven't succeeded with y-axis, though, but I guess it is less important.

Comment: Yes it did (I had answered to your answer :) ), but as I've said, I've lost the real histogram count of objects in y.

Answer (score 5):

Based on your code, this should work:

```
ax = clean.v.plot(kind='hist', bins=40, normed=True)
clean.v.plot(kind='kde', ax=ax, secondary_y=True)
ax.set(xlim=[0, Maxv])
```

You might not even need the `secondary_y` anymore.

Comment: Very clean. I've actually got rid of the `secondary_y` . The only thing is that I've lost the real count (from hist) in y, which is now normalized, but I guess that's fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Seaborn makes this easy

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.distplot(df['numeric_column'],bins=25)
```

[image]

Comment: Very true indeed. I was very beginner when I asked this question. Seaborn is very useful! :)