# plot normal distribution with pd.hist

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization

I have a pd.DataFrame which I want to plot and fit a bell curve over. I got as far as plotting the histogram. How do I fit the bell curve?

```
wordfreq = pd.DataFrame(columns=vocab, index = authors, data = rates) 
wordfreq.hist(column='the', grid = False, normed = True, color = '#9ebcda')[:25]
plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor'] = 'white'
plt.title("use of 'the' women")
```

[image: histogram]

Comment: I wonder if you mean KDE (kernal density estimate) in which case seaborn's distplot (mentioned above) will overlay by default.

Comment: Thanks, that was easy.

Comment: [**If you wanted to know how to do it without seaborn**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39987117/2336654)

Comment: The seaborn distplot plots a kernel density estimate, not the bell curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) package as:

```
seaborn.distplot(wordfreq[column])
```

Comment: the data from 0-20 disappeared. Is that because of the kde?

Comment: yeah maybe but if you don't want kde then you set it to false as `distplot(kde=False)`

Answer (score 1):

the bell curve is defined by only two parameters `mean` and `variance` which you can easily calculate via `numpy.mean` and `numpy.std`

if you want just a kernel density estimation without any parameter setting use `seaborn` and `distplot(data = wordfreq[column])`

Comment: yeah sorry, you are  totally correct and thanks for mentioning. I'll edit it